# Construct custom object from two objects

Tags: powershell, custom-object

I have two objects:

```
PropID     ValueX
---------- ------------
      8039 xxxx
      8041 xxxx
      8042 xxxx
```

```
PropID     ValueY
---------- -------
      8039 yyyy
      8041 yyyy
      8042 yyyy
```

I want to end up with a new object containing PropName,ValueX,ValueY (based on the PropID), like this:

```
PropID     ValueX       ValueY
---------- ------------ ----------
      8039 xxxx         yyyy
      8041 xxxx         yyyy
      8042 xxxx         yyyy
```

I know it's simple but I'm rusty this moring and could use a helping hand.

*Not the same as [In Powershell, what's the best way to join two tables into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848821/in-powershell-whats-the-best-way-to-join-two-tables-into-one) since I Don't want to use any third-party cmdlet but only native PowerShell.

Comment: SO is not a place where other people write code for you. What have you tried so far (show your code), and what *specific* problem (in your code) do you need help with?

Comment: there are several variants of `Merge-Object` over at the Powershell Gallery. [*grin*] have you tried any of them?

Comment: Of course I tried many things and understand you guys' point, however, I appreciate 'AdminOfThings' answer below because sometimes, you just need a helping hand to point in the right direction and it's nice to see some people are willing to help without having all the proper code in the question! Was in a hurry and now problem is solved thanks to him.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Powershell, what's the best way to join two tables into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848821/in-powershell-whats-the-best-way-to-join-two-tables-into-one)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just an example using `$o1` as the object array that contains `ValueX` and `$o2` as the object array that contains `ValueY`. Maybe this will get you started in a desirable direction.

```
$o1 = @( [pscustomobject]@{
    propID = 1
    ValueX = 334
    }) -as [collections.generic.list[object]]
$o1.add([pscustomobject]@{
    propID = 3
    ValueX = 34324
    })
$o1.add([pscustomobject]@{
    propID = 2
    ValueX = 534
    })

$o2 = @( [pscustomobject]@{
    propID = 1
    ValueY = 867
    }) -as [collections.generic.list[object]]
$o2.add([pscustomobject]@{
    propID = 2
    ValueY = 873
    })
$o2.add([pscustomobject]@{
    propID = 3
    ValueY = 89722
    })

$newobject = $o1 | Foreach-Object { 
            $_.psobject.copy()
           }
$newobject |
    Foreach-Object {
        $obj = $_
        $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ValueY -Value $o2.where{$_.propid -eq $obj.propid}.ValueY
    }
```

Comment: MUCH appreciated, super helpful in a stressful time!